# Generating Ships

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I am  trying to create a function that will randomly choose places for computer ships but it can't place them on the same spot or on another player ships.

for board I have a int[5][5] board where 0 means a place is empty 1 is for player ship and 2 is for computer ship. I wrote this but it keeps freezing and crashing android studio.

```
    boolean wrong = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        while (wrong)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int x = rand.nextInt(4);
            int y = rand.nextInt(4);

            if(board[x][y] == 1 || board[x][y] == 2){
                wrong = true;
            }

            else {
                board[x][y] = 2;
                wrong = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where do you create the board? This cannot be all the code. You need to provide something that runs.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and you should read how `Random#nextInt(..)` treats the parameter.

Comment: what is the purpose of `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` ?  remove it. Also `rand` should be initialized before the loop. No need to create new one on every loop.

Comment: @c0der It's pretty obvious that the outer loop is used to place five ships.

Comment: @Tom It's not even obvious there are ships.

Comment: How do you create and initialize ```board```?

Comment: @nicomp Only if you neither read the title nor the question text.

Comment: @Tom Not if you subscribe to properly written software.

Comment: @nicomp Yes, it is pretty strange that an obvious beginner like OP doesn't apply a proper OOP design on his/her code.

Comment: Not even OOP, basic symbol-naming. If you want to assume there are ships in there somewhere, feel free. :) The code runs the same way using ships or bicycles or US Presidents.

Comment: @nicomp You want to call the variable `board` `boardWithShips` or what? The issue isn't the naming, the issue is the type of the board. A "two-dimensional" `int` array isn't a good choice in regard of OOP design and flexibility (and code quality).

Comment: @Tom, I agree. The board should be an instance of a Board class that has a property modeling an array of objects representing  places where Ship objects can go, then there should be a Ship class. We have a classic "Has-a" relationship situation. But before OP can grasp that scenario she must understand the elementary 2D integer array.

Comment: @nicomp Btw, just as a note, you don't even actually need an array. Arrays have the issue that the board size is fixed and that you need constant bound checking to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. You can also use other types, like a Set. This needs a different approach on handling the board, but has less restrictions. But that's out of scope of this question anyway :D.

Comment: @Tom I would differ, but we can disagree without becoming disagreeable, as we have demonstrated.

Answer (score -2):

Note that you have problem with following code:

```
int x = rand.nextInt(4);
int y = rand.nextInt(4);
```

nextInt() in these invocations will provide one of these values: 0, 1, 2, 3.

Parameter for that method is not inclusive, and you will never target board[4, y] or board[x, 4] fields in the matrix.

Comment: Not the answer to the question.